# deploying web reference to azure websites

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to deploy this web reference to azure.

https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/Payment.wsdl

the reference seems to be dependent on sgen.exe which cant be found. I get this error on building at azure (it builds locally no problem).

remote: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2249,9): error MSB3086: Task could not fi
nd "sgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Window
s\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the Sdk
ToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed.

This seem to be a known problem with some discussion here http://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/task-failed-because-sgenexe-was-not-found-solution/

But no clue how to get it working on azure.

Is it possible to force the build/azure to look inside my app directory for this exe?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "building at azure" what do you mean, for Web Sites you Build locally, download your publishing settings from Azure Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/) and click Publish in VS, are you doing some sort of Continuous Development with GIT or Team Foundation Service, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: I am pushing with git and the build takes place at azure.

Comment: Hmmm, I had this problem before but not with Azure, it turned out to be  a setting in VS build config with the generation of the serialization assembly, as Windows Azure Web Sites are in preview you might want to file a bug on the MSDN? Can't really think of any other helpful answers other than circumvent GIT for the time being and using Web Deploy from VS...